# arcobject tag should be merged with arcobjects tag

Tags: support, status-completed

Not sure why there is an [arcobject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobject) tag with 6 questions by as many question askers, but it should probably merged with [arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. Done.

(Extra characters are required to post an answer...)